# RedDot LiveServer dynament error

Tags: error-code, reddot

How do I go about debugging what a return code of -26504 means? It's the result of a 'content' dynament of type 'import'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the import dynament had some issues with the content it was trying to import. I would examine this file for any possible syntax issues (if the type is XSL or XML, it will need to be valid.)

I recommend checking your rde.log for a little more information. You can probably just search for the name of the content item you're trying to import.